# Download file as index.php instead of actual file with file extension

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-download-manager

I'm facing one issue, my webview app download encoded files as an `index.php` instead of an actual file with file extension. When I download the file in the browser it works fine and downloading the actual file only faces the issue in the webview app.

If the file url is `https://example.com/file.pdf`

Then the file will download without any issue, the file.pdf will download from webview

and if the file url is `https:/example.com/index.php?r=file%2Ffile%2Fdownload&guid=cc0d950b-139d-4dfe-9b54-41b50a1052cd&hash_sha1=e8fbfebd`

then it will download as `index.php`

I have also checked the filename from  `String check_file_name = URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType);`

The result I found is `index.php`

How can I solve this

Comment: We cannot see in the code you used the filename you supplied.

Comment: @blackapps I have added an example URL of downloading file link. through the link the file is downloaded.

Comment: [File link](https://questware.itsolp.com/index.php?r=file%2Ffile%2Fdownload&guid=024aa765-095d-4d98-9bf4-98d12737c782&hash_sha1=631b61c6)